# In nextjs I want to control the output of the log

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to control the output of the log in the development environment and production environment

I can't control the log output in the react component, and I want to control the output in different development environments.

There is code compression in next.js. I want to delete console.log when compressing, but I don't know how to do it. In webpack I try to delete console.log but I get an error.

```
  config.plugins.push(
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                uglifyOptions:{
                    compress: {
                        // warnings: false,
                        drop_debugger: true,
                        drop_console: true
                    }
                }
            })
        )
        return config

error :
static/development/pages/_app.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: keyword «const» [static/development/pages/_app.js:11375,0]
```

```
function Hook_test(props) {
    const[open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const {
        dispatch,
        num
    } = props

    console.log("log test"); // I don't want to appear in a production environment，Development environment can appear
    function setReducer() {
        console.log(111111, change_add(num + 1)) dispatch(change_add(num + 1))
    }

    return ( < ><button onClick = { () = >{
            setOpen(!open);
            setReducer()
        }
    } > HOOK < /button>
            <span>{open?"打开":"关闭"}  {num}</span > </>
    )
}

class Index extends Component {
    render() {
      return   <Hook_test a={1222121}  / >
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a logging package instead of console.log?  For example, [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) is simple to set up.

Using a logging package will likely require using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/), which can be a process to start using, but if you're already using React....  If you start with [Create React App](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started), you get webpack for "free" and just need to import or require a debugging library.

Here's an example using debug with create-react-app

```
// in src/App.js 
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const debug = require('debug')('App');

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const myVar = { a: 1, b: 2 };
    debug('rendering...', myVar);
    return (....
```

Then to view debugging output, just set `localStorage.debug='*'` or to `App` from your browser Javascript console.  To view output of code run on the server side, run your server with the environment variable `DEBUG` set to `*` for all debug output, or `App`.

Comment: I have used log4js, but I can only use it in server.js. How do I use it in the react component?

Comment: Hello. Front end a website will not have access to the server file system. So you have to interact with Front End through the API, and to register the log, send a request to the server to register it. I suggest you winston. 
Logger sample code: https://gist.github.com/vikas5914/cf568748ac89446e19ecd5e2e6900443